# s3 Bucket Policy to Only Allow AWS IAM user and EC2 attached role to Access a Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want a Bucket which will only allow iam user (test) and iam role (test-role) to access to my bucket

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowTestUSER",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": ["arn:aws:iam::account-id:user/test"]
      },
      "Action": "s3:*",

      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket", "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowEC2Role",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": ["arn:aws:iam::account-id:role/test-role"]
      },
      "Action": "s3:*",

      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket", "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"]
    },

    {
      "Sid": "DenyEverythingIfNotTestUserandTestRole",

      "Effect": "Deny",
      "NotPrincipal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::account-id:user/test",
          "arn:aws:iam::account-id:role/test-role"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket", "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am expecting it to only allow a iam user and ec2 role

Comment: What is the problem? What is not working?

Comment: I am getting access denied inside Ec2 but I can access through with iam user profile locally

Comment: Have you attached this policy to a role and in turn that role to your ec2?

Comment: yes, i have s3FullAccess Attached to the role for  EC2 instance

Comment: You have two goals: (1) Allow software running on the EC2 instance to access the bucket. (2) Prevent other users/roles from accessing the bucket. Try to get #1 working first, and only after that should you do #2. Do some testing... Try removing the Deny and see if it has an impact. Use `aws sts get-caller-identity` to discover what credentials are being used to call AWS.

Comment: I wonder whether you need to reference `arn:aws:iam::account-id:role/test-role/*` since assumed roles have extra information added to the end of their ARN.

Comment: I did, the problem is in deny statement if I remove DENY block ec2 Application can access it, but it raises one new issue that other IAM users can also access this bucket..

Comment: @JatinMehrotra I just tried with a wildcard but it is not allowed in principle.

Comment: And what is the result of the `aws sts get-caller-identity` command when run on the EC2 instance?

Comment: i am getting back my account ID , user ID, and ARN with instance id

Comment: Useful info [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-restrict-amazon-s3-bucket-access-to-a-specific-iam-role/) on how to use the IAM role ID (not its ARN).

Comment: @jarmod which statement should I modify?

Comment: Review the 3rd listed policy that denies access if aws:userId is StringNotLike AROAEXAMPLEID (for the role) or AIDAEXAMPLEID (for the IAM user). But be cautious here because the wrong policy can block you accessing your own bucket (and then require root access to fix). Applying allow policies to only the specific IAM principals (user, roles, and groups) is typically safer than applying deny policies to an S3 bucket.

Comment: Thanks, @jarmod your resource was helpful

Answer (score -1):

I have got the solution by removing all allowed statements to only deny

```
   {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
          "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
          "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
          "StringNotLike": {
            "aws:userId": [
            // for getting this run 
            // aws iam get-role --role-name  test-role
            //  look for RoleId
              "AROA22222222222:*",
            // for getting this run 
            //   aws iam get-user --user-name test-user
            //  look for userId
              "AIDA1111111111",
              "root-account-id"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Putting the IAM internal identifier there has the exact same effect as putting the role and user arn there.

Comment: @luk2302 i did not get you.